# arcpy update cursor: can't connect to a database table

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, error-000972

I am using  updateCursor to retrieve some rows from a non spatial table using a connection of type "Spatial Database Connection" (That creates a .sde file) from ArcCatalog.

However, it doesn't work, I have the following error:

> (RuntimeError('ERROR 000972: Table must have Object IDs in order to be
>   sorted.',)))

Even if my table is not spatial (there is no objectid field).

Also, when I try to connect to another non spatial table from another database, It works and I can retrieve the rows.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You must add a field of data type "AutoNumber" to be able to do some functions on the table. I usually name the field "OBJECTID".

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
The table didnt have an objectid field indeed. It is not a problem in fact, because, I have just runned the command sde register, to register the table as an sde table, the primary key of the table acts like the objectid field.
The command is :
sdetable -o register -t [TABLE_NAME] -i sde:oracle11g:[SID] -c [PK_COLUMN] -C USER -u [USER] -p [PASSWORD] Thanks again